# primefaces pie chart in chrome browser it shows dark blue color shadow. when double clicking

Tags: primefaces

when doublick primefaces pie chart in chrome browser it shows dark blue color shadow.but in mozilla firefox and IE it was not happen.So how to avoid this dark blue color in chrome?

[primefaces pie chart in chrome browser it shows dark blue color shadow. when double clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882928/primefaces-pie-chart-in-chrome-browser-it-shows-dark-blue-color-shadow-when-dou)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet to solve the problem?

Comment: No,Now only i am searching a solution for that

Comment: i didnt apply any css style for that pie chart component..So how to find solution for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

> "dark blue color shadow"

Is the highlighting that chrome would apply it on the selected area, and to prevent that highlighting on the canvas area of the pie chart you would use the following CSS:

***CSS***

```css
.unselectable {
   -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

***xhtml***

```html
<p:pieChart styleClass="unselectable" />
```

Here's an online [Demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/pie/main.xhtml).

*See Also:*

- [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/user-select)

Comment: thanks..Mr.Hatem..i tried several css styles but..i cant solved that..your css code worked perfectly to my application..thanks a lot..